# lapply loop to skip to next iteration based on time elapsed

Tags: r, lapply

I'd like to create an lapply loop that will skip to the next iteration when the current iteration takes more than 60 seconds to complete.  The script includes a trycatch to deal with errors that the function might return.  I have tried using withTimeout() with no success.

```
reg.out <- lapply(1:nrow(dt), function(i) {     
    reg.mets <- withTimeout(
        tryCatch(
            1 * dt$dim1[i]),
            error = function(e) NULL), 
        timeout = 60, 
        onTimeout = "silent")      
})
```

Comment: what is `withTimeout` ?

Answer (score 2):

You've got `withTimeout` and `tryCatch` flipped.

Here is a minimal reproducible example based on the following simple function: We have a `data.frame` with `delay` times (in seconds); we then loop through the `delay` times and suspend the system by as many seconds with `Sys.sleep`.

We use `withTimeout` to skip a step if the execution time exceeds 2 seconds.

```
# Delay times from 1 to 10 seconds in 1 second steps
df <- data.frame(delay = seq(1:10))

library(R.utils)
lst <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
    cat(sprintf("Processing row %i/%i...", i, nrow(df)))
    tryCatch(
        withTimeout( {
            Sys.sleep(df$delay[i]);
            cat("[Done]\n") },
            timeout = 2),
        TimeoutException = function(ex) cat("[Skipped due to timeout]\n"))
})
#Processing row 1/10...[Done]
#Processing row 2/10...[Skipped due to timeout]
#Processing row 3/10...[Skipped due to timeout]
#Processing row 4/10...[Skipped due to timeout]
#Processing row 5/10...[Skipped due to timeout]
#Processing row 6/10...[Skipped due to timeout]
#Processing row 7/10...[Skipped due to timeout]
#Processing row 8/10...[Skipped due to timeout]
#Processing row 9/10...[Skipped due to timeout]
#Processing row 10/10...[Skipped due to timeout]
```

Note how we wrap `withTimeout` inside `tryCatch` to catch the (default) timeout error, and print a custom error message without terminating the `lapply` loop.